# Can i program games with unity by python ?? I don't know c#

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine, panda3d, gameplay3d

I want to start 3d games programming , should I start 2d first ? please give me useful course . 
Does unity accept python ? 
If not , what do you prefer( directpython, openlg,panda3d ) 
Please give me useful course . 
I'm beginner
Sorry about my bad English 
And what is game engine

If you know only one answer please answer :)

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need pure Python then you have 2D or 3D modules PyGame, Pyglet, PySDL2, Panda3D, etc.

But there is also [Godot Engine](https://godotengine.org/) which has many tools (like Unity) but it doesn't use Python - it use own language similar to Python.